# Accessing static class variables in C++?

Tags: c++, class, static

Duplicate:
**[C++: undefined reference to static class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/c-undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)**

If I have a class/struct like this

```
// header file
class Foo
{
   public:
   static int bar;
   int baz;
   int adder();
};

// implementation
int Foo::adder()
{
   return baz + bar;
}
```

This doesn't work. I get an "undefined reference to `Foo::bar'" error. How do I access static class variables in C++?

Comment: Note that you are missing a ';' after class definition.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You must add the following line in the *implementation* file:

```
int Foo::bar = you_initial_value_here;
```

This is required so the compiler has a place for the static variable.

Answer (score 20):

It's the correct syntax, however, `Foo::bar` must be defined separately, outside of the header. In one of your `.cpp` files, say this:

```
int Foo::bar = 0;  // or whatever value you want
```

Comment: Hello Chris, Is there anything wrong if we have so many public static class member variables in c++ (non multi-threaded source code). I have moved some of my global variables to a class as public static.

Answer (score 20):

You need add a line:

```
int Foo::bar;
```

That would define you a storage. Definition of static in class is similar to "extern" -- it provides symbol but does not create it. ie

foo.h

```
class Foo {
    static int bar;
    int adder();
};
```

foo.cpp

```
int Foo::bar=0;
int Foo::adder() { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

for use of static variable in class, in first you must give a value generaly (no localy) to your static variable (initialize) then you can accessing a static member in class :

```
class Foo
{
   public:
   static int bar;
   int baz;
   int adder();
};

int Foo::bar = 0;
// implementation
int Foo::adder()
{
   return baz + bar;
}
```