# Why can't access static file with this pointer?

Tags: pointers, static, this

Example I have a program:

```
class TestStatic
 {
   private:<br>
    static int staticvariable;

   public:<br>
    TestStatic() {
    this->staticvariable = 0;
    cout << this->staticvariable;
}

~TestStatic() {}
};

int main() {
 TestStatic object;
 return 0;
}
```

---

why this pointer can't access staticvariable . I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `staticvariable` is not bound to `this` but to your class.
Check out the following answers:

- [Accessing static class variables in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743203/accessing-static-class-variables-in-c)
- [Undefined reference to static class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for answering, but, i also don't know why. what is type of file this pointer can access

Comment: ah, ok ,i have just understood, the problem is not this pointer

Comment: No, the problem is not the pointer. You can access static variables using the name of the class, followed by two colons (`:`). In your case that would be `TestStatic::staticvariable`.