# How to give function template friend access to a class?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to allow template function to have friend(-like) access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922545/how-to-allow-template-function-to-have-friend-like-access)

How do I give function template `Load` friend access to class `Foo`?

The objective here is to restrict access to the constructor:  only function template `Load` may construct.

**CODE** (please ignore memory leak)

```
class Foo { 
    Foo() { } 

    template<> friend Foo const& Load<Foo>();   // error here
};

template<typename T>
T const&
Load() { return *(new T); }

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Foo const& f = Load<Foo>();
}
```

Comment: @WhozCraig - I found that before posting this, but have you tried to actually READ through that insane post?  I think the scope of that one is beyond the simplicity of this one.

Comment: You don't, actually and in fact, I'm not sure even the answers *here* are what you really want. Do you want that template function to have access to your class, but only the specialization where your class is the T-type param ? It may seem an odd question, but it is important. If so, iagreen's answer is pretty solid.

Comment: @WhozCraig - wouldn't iagreen's solution below work?  I think the scope of that one should be limited.

Comment: @kfmfe04 not the issue of scope, friend template is declaration...

Comment: It should be fine. the syntax is a little different if your class is also a template, but yours is not, so his will work very well for you. I'm more used to `friend Foo const& Load<>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```cpp
template<typename T> T const& Load() { return *(new T); }


    class Foo {
        Foo() { } 

        friend Foo const& Load<Foo>();
    };
```

Comment: +1 looks good - makes sense - seems like forward-declaration of function template is sufficient for Foo to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it like this should work:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
const T&
load(void)
{
    return *(new T);
}

class foo
{
    private:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        foo(void)
        {
            std::cout << "hello!" << std::endl;
        }
    template <typename T>
        friend const T& load();
};

int
main(void)
{
    const foo& f = load<foo>();
    return 0;
}
```