# How to trace MFC Serialize calls with Macros

Tags: c++, mfc, macros, linker-errors

I got a MFC app that is writing a huge hierarichy of objects to disk.
To make sense of what is being written I thought of logging all the calls to archive << via stream insertion and .write method by replacing those with macros

```
#pragma once
#ifndef LOGMAGIC
#define LOGMAGIC

    class LogTab
    {
    public:
        static int LogIndentCount;
        LogTab()
        {
            LogIndentCount++;
        }

        ~LogTab()
        {
            LogIndentCount--;
        }
    };

    #define ARINSERT(AR,OBJ) TRACE( "%*s %s\n", LogTab::LogIndentCount, #OBJ); AR << OBJ;
    #define ARWRITE(AR,OBJ,SIZE) TRACE("%*s %s\n", LogTab::LogIndentCount, #OBJ); AR.write(OBJ, SIZE);
#endif
```

So I created above snippet of code and put it in stdafx.h but I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int
>   LogTab::LogIndentCount" (?LogIndentCount@LogTab@@2HA)

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a better way to achieve what I am doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: undefined reference to static class member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/c-undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `LogTab::LogIndentCount` in any one of the .cpp files as,

```
#include"LogTab.h"
//...
int LogTab::LogIndentCount = 0;
```

[As a side note, if it's a multi threaded system which is using this `class` then you may think of making `LogIndentCount` synchronized (thread safe)]

Comment: You mean every cpp file that uses it?

Comment: @Hasan, No. It's only one of the `.cpp` files. Don't define in every `.cpp` file otherwise you will get multiple definition linker error.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable must be explicitly initialized.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I think your answer is on the right lines here, but it's not very clear. Example code, a link to another question (this question is a FAQ) or a more detailed explanation would be good.