# Pointer to static member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, static-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: undefined reference to static class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/c-undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)

The following C++ code compiles well (using `g++ -c`) but it doesn't link giving the error: `undefined reference to`Abc::X'`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Abc {

public:
    const static int X = 99;
};

int main()
{
    Abc a1;
    cout << &(Abc::X) << endl;
}
```

I want to know why this is not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the static member is used in a way which requires an lvalue (i.e. in a way that requires it to have an address) then it must have a definition. See the explanation at [the GCC wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#missing_static_const_definition), which includes references to the standard and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have that static member actually defined, not just declared...

Add this line before your `main()`:

```
const int Abc::X = 99;
```

As of C++17 you can also do an inline static, in which case the above additional line of code in a .cpp file is not needed:

```
class Abc {

public:
    inline const static int X = 99; // <-- "inline"
};
```

Comment: Also change the statement inside class to this: const static int X;

Comment: I was hoping Ravi would do that on his own as an additional credit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to think about translation units, static initialization order and stuff like that, just change your static constants into methods.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Abc {

public:
    inline static const int& X(){ 
      static int x=99;
      return x; 
    }
};

int main()
{
//    Abc a1;
    cout << &(Abc::X()) << endl;
}
```

Comment: In fact not looking for a quick solution. Would be glad to read detailed explanation (or links to explanations) about "translation units, static initialization order and stuff like that".

Comment: Right. There's a lot about those words on SO and google. Or even better, any entry-level book from this list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list, perhaps I'll add more later.