# __thread specifier doesn't work in C++ class

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local

I am trying to use the __thread specifier to create a thread local variable. This works OK in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static __thread int val;

int main()
{
  val = 10;
}
```

But if I try to use the __thread specifier in a class as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

class A
{
public:
  A();
  static __thread int val;
};

A::A()
{
  val = 10;
}

int main()
{
  A a;
}
```

I get the compiler error: undefined reference to 'A::val'

Comment: That is **not** a compiler error. It's a linker error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: undefined reference to static class member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/c-undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)

Answer (score 3):

You've only declared the static variable; you must also define it outside the class (in just one source file, if you have multiple source files):

```
int __thread A::val;
```

Comment: @KerrekSB: Which I'm also not familiar with :). But now I've managed to fire up the compiler, and confirm that you do need it in the definition.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Unfortunately, it is not, since __thread does not know about ctors and dtors.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Are you sure, even in `g++` with `-std=c++11`? Interesting. But I think it plays the same grammatical role.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes I am (at least for gcc 4.7, don't know if there are any plans to change it). Note that in C++11 thread_local is a storage class specifier on its own, while the gcc extension is just a "special static". So "__thread static" is similar to "thread_local".

Answer (score 0):

Static variables have to defined outside the class declaration scope. Like this:

```
int A::val;
```

Comment: *non-integral* static variables have to be *initialized* outside the class declaration, but any type can be declared within the class.

Answer (score 0):

You should define it like:

```
/\*static\*/ __thread int A::val;
```

The `__thread` keyword must be ahead of `int`.