# Static class for data storing

Tags: c++, qt, class, static

I'm pretty new to C++ language. I'm using it with Qt to create a cross-platform user interface.
The user interface will show different graphs and plots by using the same data. So I would like to have my data stored in a class (Data_Class) accessible from all the other classes.
In the data class, I am using private static variables and public static methods (get/set).

What is not clear to me is how to access the data class from the other classes. In other words, how to get data values in Class_B (from Data_Class) after I write them in Class_A (to Data_Class).

Comment: http://codepuppy.co.uk/cpptuts/GeneralFail/Globals.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this is syntax an oriented question:

```
class Data_Class {
public:
    static int a;
    static int GetA() const { return a; }
}
```

In `ClassA`:

```
Data_Class::a;
Data_Class::GetA();
```

Don't forget to add `Data_Class` [static members definitions](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/), for example into `dataclass.cpp`:

```
static int Data_Class::a = 0;
```

Otherwise you'll get an [`undefined reference` linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/c-undefined-reference-to-static-class-member).

---

You also may consider using [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (*according to comments, singleton is bad idea and you should avoid it if possible*) as [Aubin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13111966/1149736) which will take care of adding new static member definitions:

```
class Data_Class {
private:
    Data_Class();  // Prevents multiple instances

    int a;
    int b;

public:
    // Will initialize instance if needed
    static Data_Class &GetInstance(){
       static Data_Class instance;
       return instance;
    }


    int GetA() const {return a;}
};
```

Usage:

```
Data_Class::GetInstance().GetA()
```

---

Or go with little more complex but more flexible [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) which is according to wiki:

> Dependency injection is a software design pattern that allows a choice
>   of component to be made at run-time rather than compile time. This can
>   be used, for example, as a simple way to load plugins dynamically or
>   to choose mock objects in test environments vs. real objects in
>   production environments. This software design pattern injects the
>   dependent element (object or value etc) to the destination
>   automatically by knowing the requirement of the destination.

Comment: @DeadMG if you have better idea for such a simple task I'd glad to add it to my answer (I've provided more options... it's his job to study each of them and decide which one (not) use)...

Comment: @DeadMG and could you please provide source that explains why singleton is such a bad idea for small projects?

Comment: -2 - If you really need to use the singleton pattern, then at least don't do this `new/delete` rubbish. Hint: how do you know your application is closing and needs to call `DestroyInstance`? Hint: When is a static function-local variable initialized? Hint: Does C++ have a construct far superior to pointers if the pointer in question cannot (or should not) **ever** be `NULL`? Hint: Does C++ have means for memory allocation far superior to dynamic allocation if appropriate?

Comment: @Vyktor Yes, now you got static initialization order fiasco. Don't make the instance a member of the class, but a function-local variable.

Comment: Thank you. My problem was that I didn't do any initialization in the dataclass.cpp file. This fixed my issue: static int Data_Class::a = 0;

Comment: @Mikael I though so... But still I would consider using *Dependency injection* if I were you

Answer (score 1):

Given these two class declarations:

```
class A {
   public:
      static int get_data();
};

class B {
   public:
      static void do_something();
};
```

You can access A's methods from B like this:

```
void B::do_something()
{
     int the_data = A::get_data();
     // now do whatever you need to do with that data
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't have the `static` on the definition, just the declaration. IIRC, the definition outside of the class won't compile with it.