# std::count delimiter issue

Tags: c++

I have this C++ snippet that I am trying to understand:

in .hh file:

```
class A
{
private:
    //recordDelimiter is a '+' character
    // I can do this because char is an integral type!
    static const char recordDelimiter = '+';

    void f()
    {
        ....
        //serializedData is a std:;string
        //Get number of times A::recordDelimiter is found i.e. Number of objects

        // Non-Functional
        int times = (int) std::count (serializedData.begin(), serializedData.end(), A::recordDelimiter);

        // Functional
        const char recDel = A::recordDelimiter;
        int times = (int) std::count (serializedData.begin(), serializedData.end(), recDel);

        // Functional
        int times = (int) std::count (serializedData.begin(), serializedData.end(), '+');

        ....
    }
};
```

From std::count reference this is the signature of the function:

```
template <class InputIterator, class T>
  typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
    count (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
```

So I don't see why using `A::recordDelimiter` instead of `'+'` is a problem. Compiling gives me  `undefined reference to`A::recordDelimiter'`

So my question is basically, why is my non-functional code above not functional? and how come doing this :

```
const char recDel = USerializer::recordDelimiter;
```

and then pass it to std::count works?

Comment: What is the type of `serializedData` ?

Comment: This [compiles for me](http://ideone.com/OiX7xx) with some minor tweaks to fill in the missing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared, but not defined, `A::recordDelimiter`. Add this line to exactly one source code file:

```
const char A::recordDelimiter;
```

The shortcut of initializing static const members but not defining it can be thought of as providing a value, but not an actual object for the member. So this makes sense:

```
char foo = A::recordDelimiter; // just substitute '+' for the rhs here
```

but this this doesn't:

```
char *foo = & A::recordDelimiter; // Oops, no such object, so it can't have an address
```

In the case in the question, `std::count` accepts a `const T&` as a parameter. Since the object is declared but not defined, it doesn't exist. Therefore, it makes no sense to bind a reference to a non-existing object.

To be clear, it is legal to provide an initializer here, and to never define the object. But  you can't take the address of such a declared-and-initialized-but-not-defined object nor bind it to a reference.

Comment: Freaking great.  +1 because you beat me by 10 sec.

Comment: Apparently whomever -1'ed me also -1'ed you.  Real nice.

Comment: How is it that he did not define it? It says `= '+'` in the class which means it was defined right?

Comment: No Guys, it is declared and defined! char is an integral type so static const char recordDelimiter = '+'; should work. btw, I don't have a cpp file for this code.

Comment: No, @David the `= '+'` is *not* a definition. It is still a declaration.

Comment: @Rob, please take a look at the update in my post. if I capture the A::delimiter in a char then I pass it to std::count it works. How come?

Comment: No, @Kam, it is not defined. It is only declared. As a special exception to the one-definition rule, a declared-but-not-defined static const member may be used anywhere that requires a constant integral expression. That exception doesn't apply, since that context does not require a constant integral expression.

Comment: ahh I see! Thank you! I thought defining something meant, giving it a value :)

Comment: @Kam - When you define this in a source-code file, it doesn't have to be named A.cpp. You can put that one line anywhere, as long as it appears exactly once in exactly one source-code file.

Comment: I found this maybe related to this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/c-undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)

Answer (score 2):

Ah!  You declared A::recordDelimiter, but never defined it.  Is this in a header file?  If so, you'll need to add a corresponding definition for it in a source file.