# Undefined Reference in inline function, solved with unary +

Tags: c++, c++11, static, linker

I have a strange gcc 4.7 problem with c++11 enabled :

When I want to compile this:

```
constexpr unsigned int getDim(const int e){
        return (e==1)?  A::Set::Dimension :
            (
              (e==2)? B::Set::Dimension :

                (
                    (e==3)? C::Set::Dimension :
                    (
                       +D::Set::Dimension

                    )
                )
            );
 }
```

where for each struct `A,B,C,D` a typedef for `Set` is defined  where the related Set has an int `Dimension`, for example

```
struct SetOne{
   static const int Dimension = 1;
}

struct A{
   typedef SetOne Set;
}
```

**If I don't use the `unary +` infront of `D::Set::Dimension` the linker fails complaining about undefined references to SetOne::Dimension.**

Is this the same problem as: [Undefined reference to static class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)

I cannot give a MWE as the problem vanished for a simple example with one .cpp file. ?
(but all definitions are for A,B,C,D are in one header file)

Does anybody have a clue what might go wrong here? This is unintuitiv :-)

**Observation 2:**
If one replaces: `+D::Set::Dimension` with 0, it compiles fine, but why the hack the other statements as `A::Set::Dimension` do not rise the same linking error?

Comment: Yes, your assumption about previously answered question seems to be true. `static const int Dimension = 1;` inside class declaration is only a static variable declaration, not definition (despite initialization). You should explicitly define static members of a class outside its declaration.

Comment: If I define the static members outside of the class decleration in a cpp file then I cannot use the static int in a template function ``f<Set::Dimension>`` as the compiler needs to see the const expression ...? How can I avoid this?

Comment: If you are using for such purposes only static variables of integral type, you may initialize them inside your class and create their definitions outside of the class **without** any initialization. **Initialization is not the same as definition.** If you can use C++11 you may also try to use `constexpr` keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the expression you are building, the ternary expression is yielding an *lvalue*, which causes the *odr-use* of the static constant. The One Definition Rule requires that all static members that are *odr-used* are **defined**, so you need to provide a definition (in a single translation unit).

> So why does the problem go away with the unary +?

The unary `+` does not cause the *odr-use* of the static member, it only requires an *rvalue*, and the result of it is another *rvalue*. That cascades out through the conditional operators as once one of the two arguments is an *rvalue* the result of the expression will also be an *rvalue*. The end result is that the single `+` has the effect of forcing the *lvalue-to-rvalue* conversion of all of the static consts used in the function and removes the *odr-uses*.

> If one replaces: +D::Set::Dimension with 0, it compiles fine

Again, 0 is an *rvalue*, and it will have the same effect as the unary `+` described above.