# Static class function in different class

Tags: c++

I am trying to call the static function AreaMap::staticInitialize(Model *) from a method in the class View. It compiles when I define the class AreaMap first but I get the error show below when I try declaring View first even though I forward declared AreaMap. Anyone know a way to keep the definition of View at the top?

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H
#include "Model.h"

class AreaMap;

class View {
 public:
  void linkMvc(Model * m) {
    model = m;
    AreaMap::staticInitialize(m);
  }

  Model * model;
};

class AreaMap {
 public:
  void static staticInitialize(Model * m) {
    model = m;
  }
  Model * model;

};
#endif
```

Error:

```
inc/View.hpp: In member function ‘void View::linkMvc(Model*, Controller*)’:
inc/View.hpp:36:7: error: incomplete type ‘AreaMap’ used in nested name specifier
       AreaMap::staticInitialize(m);
```

Comment: what abt the `Model` ?

Comment: Put the body of `View::linkMvc` after the `AreaMap`. Or make the function just be a free function instead of a static member function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H

class AreaMap;

class View {
 public:
  void linkMvc(Model * m);

  Model * model;
};

class AreaMap {
 public:
  void static staticInitialize(Model * m) {
    model = m;
  }
  Model * model;

};

void View::linkMvc(Model * m) {
  model = m;
  AreaMap::staticInitialize(m);
}

#endif
```

However, this still shouldn't compile. `staticInitialize()` attempts to modify a non-static member variable.

Comment: sorry spoke too soon. I am getting a linking error. It says multiple definitions of View::linkMvc

Comment: Did you remove the definition of `linkMvc` from the class definition? Without more information, it will be difficult to help. The code I've shown above (with a fix for the mentioned bug) does compile: http://ideone.com/D9f0g0

Comment: obj/moc_View.o: In function `AreaMap::staticInitialize(Model*)':
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:104: multiple definition of `View::linkMvc(Model*, Controller*)'

Comment: I am using g++ and compiling and linking separately. On the linking step I get the multiple definition error and following is "undefined reference to `AreaMap::model"

Comment: Ok. putting staticInitialize() in a View.cpp file got rid of the multiple definition error. I am still getting "undefined reference to `AreaMap::model"

Comment: Ok. Apparently you have to define it outside the class as well. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member) I added "Model * AreaMap::model;" to the View.cpp file and that fixed the undefined reference error.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AreaMap;                       <----- This won't suffice.

class View {
 public:
  void linkMvc(Model * m) {          <----- What's Model?
    model = m;
    AreaMap::staticInitialize(m);    <----- What's this?
  }

  Model * model;
};
```

There are two problems here:

- What's `Model`? You should be forward declaring it.
- Your forward declaration of class `AreaMap` does not suffice for calling `AreaMap::staticInitialize`. You need to declare that function before you can reference it.

Comment: Model is in another header file. Sorry there should be a #include "Model.h" at the top there.

Comment: And AreaMap::staticInitialize() is a static function defined in AreaMap.

Comment: @user1505520 - (1) If the header only needs to know that `Model` is some class, all that is needed is a forward declaration. But something is needed. (2) I know what `AreaMap::staticInitialize` is. I can read ahead to the next class definition. The problem is that the compiler doesn't read ahead like that.