# constexpr array not defined

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constexpr

I'm with c++11. I'm trying to initialice a multidimensional array. The first try was

```
const static int COORDINATES[4][4][2]={{{-1,-1},{0,0},{1,1},{2,0}},
                                       {{-1,1},{0,0},{1,-1},{0,-2}},
                                        {{1,1},{0,0},{-1,-1},{-2,0}},
                                         {{1,-1},{0,0},{-1,1},{0,2}}};
```

Compiler complained about a constexpr, so I wrote

```
constexpr const static int COORDINATES[4][4][2]={{{-1,-1},{0,0},{1,1},{2,0}},
                                       {{-1,1},{0,0},{1,-1},{0,-2}},
                                        {{1,1},{0,0},{-1,-1},{-2,0}},
                                         {{1,-1},{0,0},{-1,1},{0,2}}};
```

No erros, but when I use the array in a method, get an error. I don't understand...

```
void LShape::rotateShape(Square* cloneSquares) {
    int var=COORDINATES[1][1][1]; //no problems
    int x=2;
    var=COORDINATES[0][x][0]; //error 'not defined' because of x
                             //if changed to number, works
}
```

The error:

```
LShape.cpp:23: referencia a `LShape::COORDINATES' sin definir //reference to L...S not defined
```

Where line 23 is the second use of COORDINATES

My complete code, LShape header

```
#ifndef LSHAPE_H 
#define LSHAPE_H

#include "Square.h"
#include "EmptySquare.h"
#include "Shape.h"

class LShape : public Shape {

public:
LShape();
LShape(const LShape& orig);
virtual ~LShape();

inline int getState() {return state;}
inline int getNUMBER_OF_STATES() {return NUMBER_OF_STATES;}
inline int getNUMBER_OF_SQUARES() {return NUMBER_OF_SQUARES;} 

void rotateShape(Square* cloneSquares);


private:
int state;
static const int NUMBER_OF_STATES=4;
static const int NUMBER_OF_SQUARES=4;


constexpr const static int INITIAL_COORDINATES[3][2]={{1,0},{1,0},{1,1}};

constexpr const static int COORDINATES[4][4][2]={{{-1,-1},{0,0},{1,1},{2,0}},
                                       {{-1,1},{0,0},{1,-1},{0,-2}},
                                        {{1,1},{0,0},{-1,-1},{-2,0}},
                                         {{1,-1},{0,0},{-1,1},{0,2}}}; 


};
#endif  /* LSHAPE_H */
```

LShape code

```
#include "../../include/LShape.h"

LShape::LShape() : Shape(){
    //numberSquares=4;
    //squares = new Square[numberSquares];
}

LShape::~LShape(){
    //dtor
}

LShape::LShape(const LShape& other){
    //copy ctor
}


void LShape::rotateShape(Square* cloneSquares) {

    int var=COORDINATES[1][1][1]; //no problems
    int x=2;
    var=COORDINATES[0][x][0]; //error not defined
}
```

By the way, I'm newbie in C++, don't be bad with me :)

EDIT: I'm using the default compiler in linux (GCC) the IDE is using the following command

```
g++ -std=c++11   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/shape/LShape.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/shape/LShape.o src/shape/LShape.cpp
```

Comment: you include shape.h before you define the coordinates !

Comment: @Christophe I can't see what is the problem with that... coordinates is only in LShape, not shape

Comment: @Piotr S. I'm using the default compiler in linux (GCC) the IDE is using the following command
g++ -std=c++11   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/shape/LShape.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/shape/LShape.o src/shape/LShape.cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the array is a class member is an important part of this puzzle.

`static constexpr` (and in some cases, also `const`) class members have a special rule that they don't require a definition if they are never odr-used.  But your program does odr-use the variable, so according to the C++ standard you need a definition.

- [Undefined reference to static class member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/272900/103167)

The reason the behavior changed between `2` and `x` is that in the former case the optimizer was able to eliminate runtime access to the array.  But you can't rely on this<sup>1</sup>, the rule is that the definition is required if there is an odr-use.

Here's the full rule, found in section 9.4.2 (`[class.static.data]`):

> If a non-volatile `const static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition  can  specify  a  *brace-or-equal-initializer*  in  which  every  *initializer-clause*  that  is  an  *assignment-
>   expression*  is a constant expression (5.19).  A `static` data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier;  if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression.  [ Note:  In both these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions.  — end note ] **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.**

---

In other circumstances, the optimization *is* required.  For example, you could use

```
var = sizeof (char[COORDINATES[0][2][0]]);
```

which is never an odr-use of `COORDINATES`.  But this guarantee is made only where a constant expression is required, like in an array bound, and not in general.

Of course things go wrong if you try to use a negative array bound.  So maybe you'd prefer:

```
enum { varc = COORDINATES[0][2][0] };
var = varc;
```

The point is using it in a context which absolutely must be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: I put constexpr const int LShape::COORDINATES[4][4][2]; at the end of header and now compile. Hope it don't give more problems, haha. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `constexpr' and was able to compile the code at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php

```
const static int COORDINATES[4][4][2]={{{-1,-1},{0,0},{1,1},{2,0}},
                                      {{-1,1},{0,0},{1,-1},{0,-2}},
                                      {{1,1},{0,0},{-1,-1},{-2,0}},
                                      {{1,-1},{0,0},{-1,1},{0,2}}}; 


void LShape_rotateShape() 
{

    int var=COORDINATES[1][1][1]; //no problems
    int x=2;
    var=COORDINATES[0][x][0]; //error not defined
}
```

I compiled it successfully with the following compilers:

- C++ Online (GNU GCC version 4.8.1)
- C++11 Online (GNU GCC version 4.7.2)