# Trying to use static class variable to create new ID for objects

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and when I try to run this program it tells me: "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int Plate::plate_nID". I am right now just trying to create the plate class and print out the ID. Not sure where I went wrong.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Plate{
   private:
      int id;
      string plateName;
      static int plate_nID;

      int generateID(){
         plate_nID++;
         return plate_nID;
      }
   public:
      Plate(string name){
         plateName = name;
         id = generateID();
      }
      ~Plate(){}
      int getID(){
         return id;
      }
      string getName(){
         return plateName;
      }
};
```

Here is my main:

```
#include "Plate.cpp"
#include "PlateNode.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(){
Plate s=Plate::Plate("p1");
cout << s.getID();}
```

I have looked at this question:
[Undefined reference to static class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/vectorpush-back-odr-uses-the-value-causing-undefined-reference-to-static-clas)
which similar questions to mine were marked as dulpicates of, but I when I try to do that it tells me: cannot instantiate non-static member outside of class. Please Help!

Comment: Alternatively make `plate_nID` a static inside the function `generateID` (Which itself should be static)

Comment: Consider `Plate(const string& name)` and `const string& getName() const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `static` member variable outside the class. Something along the lines of:

```
int Plate::plate_nID = 0;
```

Comment: @ChrisMurphy, It has to be outside the class, in a .cpp file.

Comment: I tried to put it inside the Plate.cpp filw but then when I try to instantiate a plate in the main file it says plate_nID already defined

Comment: You should not `#include` a .cpp file in another .cpp file. `#include` only .h files. Compile the .cpp files separately and link the resulting object files to create an executable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the static variable outside your class, only then will your code work

```
int Plate::plate_nID = 0;
```

You must define it outside the class (preferably outside the main()  )

Probably better to define it right after your class.