# Undefined reference to static constexpr char[][]

Tags: c++

I tried to init char[][] static public field in class but in another function this field is undefined. How I use consexpr  or exists another method to init static (dictionary) array?

```
class A {
    public:
        constexpr static char dict[][3] = {
            "a",
            "bb"
        };

        void print() {
            printf(A::dict[1]);
        }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

10  undefined reference to `A::dict'

Comment: Any reason you can't use a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: This question uses `constexpr`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/ does not.  Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition needs to go outside the class, while the initializer belongs inside the class.

```
constexpr char A::dict[][3];
```