# Undefined reference to static header method

Tags: c++, class, methods, header, init

My program is returning Undefined reference to Data::init(). It's all declared correctly as far as I can tell. The method is prototyped in Data.h and filled in Data.cpp and called in main.cpp. The code was written in Visual Studio and it shows no errors with not being able to find methods.

Data.h

```
#ifndef DATA_H_
#define DATA_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "Controls.h"
#include "Sensors.h"
#include "Auto.h"
#include "AI.h"

class Data
{
public:
    static void init();
    static Sensors getSensors();
    static Auto getAuto();
    static Controls getControls();
    static AI getAI();

private:
    static Controls controls;
    static Sensors sensors;
    static AI brains;
    static Auto auton;
};

#endif
```

Data.cpp

```
#include "Data.h"

using namespace std;


void Data::init()
{
    Data::controls;
    Data::sensors;
    Data::brains;
    Data::auton;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Data.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Data::init();  // Initialize Data

    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling through cmd with g++ 4.8.1

I've tried making the method static in Data.cpp and most of the errors on the internet are due to forgetting to add the `Data::` before init in the .cpp file.

CMD

```
g++ main.cpp
undefined reference to `Data::init()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What is your linker command line? Is `Data.cpp` part of the project source files?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/272900/951890

Comment: You don't have the static data members defined properly.  They need to be outside the function.

Comment: Data.cpp is part of the source files. I'm using g++ with cmd.

Comment: Outside what function?

Comment: @DSchana Can you please post your exact g++ command line in your question? Regarding the data members, you have to put the definiitions outside of the init function with type.

Comment: You forgot to add `Data.cpp` to the compilation and linking process.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by linking process. I never set anything like that.

Comment: @DSchana Read up the duplicate Q&A, its all explained in detail there.

Comment: Yea I see it thanks.