# Undefined reference: trying to initialize pointer array of objects from different class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, undefined-reference

The solution from the ["duplicated from" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member) is to initialize the pointer after the class definition but I have found no success doing so. Trying to insert `A B::AArray;` or `A B::AArray = new A[10];` gives me multiple errors including "conflicting declaration" and "cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression". I can't seem to find a way to define B::AArray anywhere in the code.

```
class A{
public:
    int Avar;
    A(int Avar = 0){this->Avar = Avar;}
};

class B{
private:
    static A *AArray;
public:
    static void setAArray();
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}

void B::setAArray(){
    A *data;
    data = new A[10];
    AArray = data; // <- delete this line and the program complies
}
```

This piece of code says I have an undefined reference to 'B::AArray' and won't compile. How do I resolve this if I want a static pointer to an array of class A objects in class B?

Note: my class does not use multiple files currently and everything is under one .cc file

Comment: Did you try adding `A* B::AArray = nullptr;` after the definition of `class B` (just like the "'duplicate from' question" says) and later in `B::setAArray` to redirect the pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the content of the previous duplicate, a more detailed working sample of the OP code follows.

The definition needs to outside the function;

```
class B{
private:
    static A *AArray;
public:
    static void setAArray();
};

A* B::AArray = nullptr; // define and initialise with a suitable default

int main(){
    return 0;
}

void B::setAArray(){
    A *data;
    data = new A[10];
    AArray = data; // initialization...
}
```

The `AArray = data;` is not a definition, it is an initialization.

[Sample listing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ecd3ab37397b97f).