# Set and get Singleton variables from and in another class with c++ / QT creator

Tags: c++, qt, get, set, singleton

im new in c++

my problem: this is my singleton:

```
class Singleton
{
    static Singleton *singletonInstance;
    Singleton() {}

    public:
    int numero = 0;

    static Singleton* getSingletonInstance()
    {
        //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
        if(singletonInstance == nullptr)
        {
            singletonInstance = new Singleton();
        }
        return singletonInstance;
    }
};
```

this is another file .cpp where i set or get the "numero" variable:

```
Singleton.getSingletonInstance()->numero = 10;
```

I get this error:

> error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
>
> Singleton.getSingletonInstance()->numero = 10;

How do to set "numero" variable and get/set the numero from sigleton in/from other class .cpp ?
My target is use this singleton. I'm new in c++.
Where I wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The symbol `Singleton` is not an object, it's a class. For that you have to use the *scoping operator* `::`:

```
Singleton::getSingletonInstance()->numero = 10;
```

Comment: error: undefined reference to 'Singleton::singletonInstance', maybe I should rewrite singleton class ?

Comment: getSingletonInstance @Some programmer dude

Comment: @Mr.Developer You will have to define `Singleton Singleton::*singletonInstance = nullptr` in your source somewhere , I guess

Comment: @Mr.Developer That's a problem for another question actually. And that question have been answered *many* times . [For example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member).

Comment: @P0W: It should be: `Singleton Singleton::singletonInstance = nullptr;` without the `*`. You have to define that after your class in your `class.cpp`

Comment: @AndreKampling No the instance variable is declared as a pointer so the definition needs to be one too. But the asterisk should be moved.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yeah you're right. Where was my head...? It has to be: `Singleton* Singleton::singletonInstance = nullptr;`

Comment: @Mr.Developer: You have to define your static variable additionally after the class like this: `class Singleton { ... }; Singleton* Singleton::singletonInstance = nullptr;`