# Undefined reference to a static instance of an inner class

Tags: c++, c++11, static, inner-classes

I've the following class called as **Point** which also contains an inner class called as **PointFactory**. The Point class has a static instance of the inner class **PointFactory** as **Factory** present inside it.

```
    class Point{

    private:
        float x, y;
        Point(float a, float b){
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }

    public:
        struct PointFactory{

                PointFactory(){}

                Point newCartesian(float x, float y){
                    return {x, y};
                }

                Point newPolar(float rho, float theta){
                    return {rho*cos(theta), rho*sin(theta)};
                }
            };
        static PointFactory Factory();
    };
```

I'm trying to access the methods - **newCartesian** and **newPolar** from the the static instance **Factory** as follows:

```
Point point = Point::Factory.newCartesian(10, 20);
Point point2 = Point::Factory.newPolar(100, 200);
```

But, I get 2 errors saying that the methods **newCartesian** and **newPolar** couldn't be resolved. I understand the static variables need to be initialized and I believe I've done that.

I would like to know the reason for the above mentioned errors.

Comment: You use `Point::Factory`, but what *is* `Point::Factory`? Is it an object?

Comment: Yes, it's a static object, which is defined as: `static PointFactory Factory();` in the Point class.

Comment: No it's not a static object. It's a static ***function***. And as all functions it needs to be *called*.

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: Not directly related but that factory idea is bad. check that: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aa2de8e4a219c57 Variations possible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've also tried to change it as: `static PointFactory Factory;`. But, now I get the following error during run-time: `undefined reference to `Point::Factory'`

Comment: For that error, dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. Here is an alternate solution that kindi keep your syntax: https://pastebin.com/rGDJzNeu