# What is the last line of this code doing?

Tags: c++

I have never seen this:

```
class myclass{
    static int value;
};
int myclass::value(5);
```

This is a short version of a code that i see in the book C++ Concurrency in Action, but i don't get what is that declaration of a static class value out of the class block like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to static class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)

Comment: Not completly, in that qustion i can see that is a declaration of the value, but why is a 5 betweeen parenthesis?

Comment: So, the "5" would be the static initialization of the value + declaration?

Comment: `static int value;` is the declaration. `int myclass::value(5);` is the definition. The definition is equivalent to `int myclass::value = 5;`.

Comment: This line initializes the static member. I think u r using the old edition before c++17 because with c++ 17. you can initialize the static members inside the definition of the class, as follows

    class myclass{
        inline static int value {5};
    };

Answer (score 0):

1. `::` is known as scope resolution operator and one of the purpose of it is to access a class’s static variables outside class and it seems above piece of code is doing same initializing it outside class.
2. One of the ways to initialize variables in c++, known as constructor initialization, is done by enclosing the initial value between parentheses (()):
   So  int myclass::value(5); is equivalent to int myclass::value = 5;