# static std::mutex shared by all the instances of a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a non-blocking `Timer` class that:

- counts down from whatever `int` the class is instantiated with
- each new instance of the class waits for any timer that is currently running to first finish before they start counting down

### Current Design of class:

```
class Timer{
private: 
  std::thread *thread;

public:
  Timer(const int &timer, std::mutex *mutex){
    this->thread = new std::thread(
        [&timer, mutex](){
          mutex->lock();
          std::cout<<"Counting to: "<<timer<<std::endl;
          for (int i=0; i < timer; i++) {
            std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
            sleep(1);
          }
          std::cout<<"Time is up"<<std::endl;
          mutex->unlock();
    });
  }

  ~Timer(){
    this->thread->join();
    delete this->thread;
  }
};
```

I am calling it from main with this:

```
int main() {
  std::mutex mutex;
  Timer time(3, &mutex);
  Timer newTime(9, &mutex);
  //Do something else in the meantime ...
  return 0;
}
```

---

### Quesion:

I would like to simplify the `main` by internalising the `mutex` as a static variable of the class. Something like this:

- a simpler `main`

```
int main() {
  Timer time(3);
  Timer newTime(9);
  //Do something else in the meantime ...
  return 0;
}
```

- a more representative Timer class:

```cpp
class Timer{
private: 
  std::thread *thread;
  static std::mutex timerMutex;

public:
  Timer(const int &timer){
    this->thread = new std::thread(
        [&timer, this](){
          timerMutex.lock();
          std::cout<<"Counting to: "<<timer<<std::endl;
          for (int i=0; i < timer; i++) {
            std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
            sleep(1);
          }
          std::cout<<"Time is up"<<std::endl;
          timerMutex.unlock();
    });
  }

  ~Timer(){
    this->thread->join();
    delete this->thread;
  }
};
```

- **How can I do this ?**

---

### Current Error:

```
 error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Presumably the linker error is an undefined symbol for `Timer::timerMutex`?

Comment: If I replace the static definition with: `Timer::timerMutex` I get: 
`error: extra qualification on member 'timerMutex'
  static std::mutex Timer::timerMutex;` so the answer from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member) does not seem to work

Comment: I see, I must create the `Timer::timerMutex` outside the class. Interesting that instantiating a class element doesn't instantiate the static elements. thank you

Comment: `inline static` in the class declaration works in C++17 without the need to define the variable elsewhere.

Comment: oh, that's interesting! Thanks for sharing. @PaulSanders