# C++ how to use static map member

Tags: c++

I need to have a uniq map object to store key-vlaue globally. So I created a class with a static unordered_map as the member, my code as following please:

```
class PopMap {
    public:
        static unordered_map<string, string> dataMap;
        PopMap(){};
        ~PopMap(){};
};
int main(){
    PopMap::dataMap["name"]="Tom";
    return 0;
}
```

But I got the following exception: `undefined reference to PopMap::dataMap`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static: "The declaration inside the class body is not a definition".  So you need a definition `unordered_map<string, string> PopMap::dataMap;` at top level.  Example: https://godbolt.org/z/WeTssP

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member/272965#272965