# Why can't I use google test's ASSERT_TRUE for my SFINAE check?

Tags: c++, googletest, sfinae

I have a simple SFINAE check for the existence of a static member function using C++17's `std::void_t`:

```cpp
template <class T, class X = void>
struct has_bar {
    static const bool value = false;
};
template <class T>
struct has_bar<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::bar(std::declval<int&>()))>> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

The class `Foo` obviously has a `bar` member function taking an `int&` as its only argument, the class `NoBar` has no such member function:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    static void bar(int& value)
    {
        value = 42;
    }
};

struct NoBar{};
```

Using `has_bar` in a `static_assert` works as expected, but using it in an `ASSERT_TRUE` statement yields a compiler error:

```cpp
TEST(SFINAE, has_bar)
{
    static_assert(!has_bar<NoBar>::value);
    static_assert(has_bar<Foo>::value);
    ASSERT_FALSE(has_bar<NoBar>::value);

    //why does this not work??
    ASSERT_TRUE(has_bar<Foo>::value);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/ccfSP5vL.o: in function `SFINAE_has_bar_Test::TestBody()':
/home/ce/<source>:42: undefined reference to `has_bar<Foo, void>::value'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Is this a google test bug or am I missing something here?

- Live Code C++17: https://godbolt.org/z/fj8z6b
- Live Code C++14: https://godbolt.org/z/n7TvqW

Comment: Does it pass if you change the check to `ASSERT_TRUE((bool)has_bar<Foo>::value);` ? I know it seems pointless, but humor me please.

Comment: Yes it does! Weird...Could you explain?

Comment: It's pretty much the same explanation as presented in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/272982/817643). Seems the macro hides some sort of reference binding.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!  I would never have found this so quickly...

Comment: Happy to help. Unlike the answer I linked though, I wouldn't recommend a macro. A possible solution is not to define `value` yourself. Instead your trait could inherit from `std::false_type` and `std::true_type`. The standard library should be handling the ODR correctly.

Comment: HInt: derive from std::false_type or std::true_type instead of defining static member value (both types from type_traits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because `has_bar::value` has been declared but not defined. Somehow, the `ASSERT_TRUE` macro has odr-used this object. It's not necessary to understand exactly what `ASSERT_TRUE` is doing; you should always define your static class members.

The easiest way to do this is to inherit from `std::false_type` and `std::true_type` instead of declaring a static member named `value`. The standard library already contains a definition for the inherited `value` member, so you don't have to provide your own.

In C++17, note that `static constexpr bool value = false;` *is* a definition by itself (and is implicitly `inline`). But this isn't the case if the member is merely `const` and not `constexpr`, so you see the issue in both C++14 and C++17 mode.