# undefined reference to in c++ / omnet++

Tags: c++, c++11, omnet++

I am using omnet++ that follows c++, I want to make one simple controller.
I want to change the value of static members of the controller from another file. But when I compile the code it generates undefined references.

My code is written following, Kindly suggest to me what should I do, Thanks in advance.

```
//controlTest.h
namespace OPTxGsPON {
class controlTest:public cSimpleModule, public cListener 
{
public:
    static int bbb;

protected:
    virtual void initialize();
};
}; //namespace
```

```
//controlTest.cc
#include "controlTest.h"
namespace OPTxGsPON {
void controlTest::initialize()
{
    controlTest::bbb = 0;
}
}; //namespace
```

```
//User.h
#include "controlTest.h"

namespace OPTxGsPON {
class User :public cSimpleModule
{
protected:
    virtual void initialize();
};
}; //namespace
```

```
//User.cc
#include "controlTest.h"
#include "User.h"

namespace OPTxGsPON {
void User::initialize()
{
     controlTest::bbb=12;
}
}; //namespace
```

**Error:**
../out/gcc-release/src/User/User.o:User.cc:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN9OPTxGsPON11controlTest2bbE[.refptr._ZN9OPTxGsPON11controlTest2bbE]+0x0): undefined reference to `OPTxGsPON::controlTest::bbb'

Please guide me How will I fix it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You need to define the static class members -- you've only declared them.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member).

Comment: Thank you very much for help but it gives the same error when I define members in 
```
//controlTest.cc
void controlTest::initialize()
{
    controlTest::bbb = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] and state any error message(s) verbatim.

Comment: That is not how you initialize state members. View the bottom of the second answer in the duplicate post.

Comment: Respected members, I have tried mentioned examples but these are not working, yes if I write 
'static const int bbb = 0;'  in controlTest.h 
then it again gives another error, like 
assignment of read-only variable 'OPTxGsPON::controlTest::bbb   in User.cc

Comment: You are still not following what is in the linked post. Also, you can search for static class variable initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you JHBonarius, G.M and ChrisMM , All of your guidance.
Again, I follow the last comment of  ChrisMM, and again tried to search suitable solution and I got it. The following code is running well.

```
//controlTest.h
namespace OPTxGsPON {
class controlTest:public cSimpleModule, public cListener 
{
public:
   static inline int bbb; //using inline word but really I do not know what is inline meaning!

protected:
    virtual void initialize();
};
}; //namespace

//controlTest.cc
#include "controlTest.h"
namespace OPTxGsPON {
void controlTest::initialize()
{}
}; //namespace
```

```
//User.h
#include "controlTest.h"
namespace OPTxGsPON {
class User :public cSimpleModule
{
protected:
    virtual void initialize();
};
}; //namespace

//User.cc
#include "controlTest.h"
#include "User.h"

namespace OPTxGsPON {
void User::initialize()
{
    controlTest::bbb=12;
}
}; //namespace
```

```
//Server.h
#include "controlTest.h"
class Server :public cSimpleModule
{
protected:
    virtual void finish();
};
}//namespace

//Server.cc
#include "controlTest.h"
#include "Server.h"
namespace OPTxGsPON {
void Server::finish()
{
    std::cout<<"WoW! Server got value  = "<<controlTest::bbb<<endl;
}
}//namespace

The output is WoW! Server got value  = 12
```

Thank you very much ...