# C++ Linkage Error using static vectors. shape example

Tags: c++, linkage

I have a linkage error in this code. can someone solve this problem and explain why does it happen?

Header file

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Shape
{
public:
    static void test_shapes();

    // static becuase every shape that created added to this list
    static std::vector<Shape*> _shapes;

};
```

Source file

```
#include "Shape.h"

void Shape::test_shapes()
{
    _shapes.size();
}
```

Comment: Maybe this one helps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/272900/1741542

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to static class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member)