# undefined symbol：private: static struct blink::WrapperTypeInfo

Tags: c++, chromium, blink

try to add a custom member [mutable Member inWin_;] into blink DOMWindow and use like this
[use the menber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LeUk.png)
But there is a problem with linking
[link error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBWOT.png)
and then i find the error source but i don't kown how to solve it
[error source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ5B1.png)
[my class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b40s3.png)

Comment: Please don't post images instead of code, post the relevant source code instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272900/undefined-reference-to-static-class-member

Comment: Please use code blocks in stackoverflow or using external platforms like https://www.paste.org/122555 , but stackoverflow has better block for code sharing.

Comment: ok，i got it，i will use code blocks next time

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have forgotten to include the file containing `wrapperTypeInfo`. You should probably add a line similar to

```cpp
#include "WrapperTypeInfo.h"
```

Comment: In fact I have included the header file

Answer (score -1):

i have solved the problem now!
the wrong behavior is that i try to add an blink/.../module/../myAPI  into  blink/.../core/.../DOMWindow .
to solve it i change myAPI into blink/.../core
now link success